How to copy selected cells to array (VBA, Excel)
There is a problem that I cannot solve (ok, it's 2am) and I would like to ask you for your support.
I have an Excel sheet with some numbers and text in few cells. A lot of cells are empty:




A
B
C
D
E
...




1
text
999






2
56

what?
12




3


at





4








...









I'm wondering how to obtain using VBA a 2D array with following properties:

the size reflects the whole rectangular range that contains numbers or text (A1:D3);
contains only numeric values (999, 56 and 12);
has these numeric values with indices assigned, that reflect their position in the spreadsheet.

The resulting array should be defined like this:
arr(0, 0) = Empty
arr(0, 1) = 999
arr(0, 2) = Empty
arr(0, 3) = Empty
arr(1, 0) = 56
arr(1, 1) = Empty
arr(1, 2) = Empty
arr(1, 3) = 12
arr(2, 0) = Empty
arr(2, 1) = Empty
arr(2, 2) = Empty
arr(2, 3) = Empty

My approach so far looks as follows:

Specify the range by identifying last row and last column containing text or numbers (works good):

lastRow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lastCol = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column



Select cells that contain numbers only (works good):

Set rg = ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
rg.Select


Populate array - AND THAT'S EXACTLY WHERE I'M STUCK :-(

Your help is much appreciated!
Max

Solution: loop over each cell in selected range:
For Each cell In rg
    arr(cell.Row, cell.Column) = cell.Value
Next


Try Dim arr  As Variant :  arr=rg.Value


arrData is one-base index. that is, the first item is arrData(1,1).

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k
    Dim arrData
    arrData = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)
            If Not IsNumeric(arrData(i, j)) Then arrData(i, j) = k
        Next j
    Next i
    Stop
End Sub


Try this:
Sub CreateArray()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, a, arr, cell As Range, rg As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    a = ws.UsedRange.Value
    Set rg = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    ReDim arr(0 To UBound(a) - 1, 0 To UBound(a, 2) - 1)
    For Each cell In rg
        arr(cell.Row - 1, cell.Column - 1) = cell.Value
    Next cell
    Debug.Print IsEmpty(arr(0, 0))  ' True
    Debug.Print arr(0, 1)  ' 999
    Debug.Print arr(1, 0)  ' 56
End Sub

